# Inserting rows in SQL, Keep getting error message #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi am trying to add in rows to my table "`members`" however i keep getting an error message.

```
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I have another table called "`user`" where I have the `user_id` as the primary key. In members table I have user_id as the foreign key.

Can anyone help me?

> INSERT INTO members (user_id, membership_number, weight, height,
>   progress, meal_plan, my_programme, trainer_id, bank, card_number,
>   sort_code, valid, exp, security_number) VALUES ('2','0001','75kgs',
>   '6ft', 'lost 5kgs', 'chicken and rice', '2', 'HSBC',
>   '1234123412341234', '401725', '01-12', '01-16', '521');

Comment: The value of user id in member table must have to be already there in users table. Please check this.

Comment: my_programme or  trainer_id , one of value is missing

Comment: Hi, yes 'user_id' is in users table and it is "2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting only 13 values..you are missing  `my_programme` value..

```
#  field             value
--------------------------
 1 user_id           2
 2 membership_number 0001
 3 weight            75kgs
 4 height            6ft
 5 progress          lost 5kgs
 6 meal_plan         chicken and rice
 7 my_programme      ?????
 8 trainer_id        2
 9 bank              HSBC
10 card_number       1234123412341234
11 sort_code         401725
12 valid             01-12
13 exp               01-16
14 security_number   521
```

---

```
INSERT INTO members (user_id, membership_number, weight, height, progress, meal_plan,
my_programme, trainer_id, bank, card_number, sort_code, VALID, exp, security_number)
VALUES ('2',
        '0001',
        '75kgs',
        '6ft',
        'lost 5kgs',
        'chicken and rice',
        'some value', <------------- Value for my_programme 
        '2',
        'HSBC',
        '1234123412341234',
        '401725',
        '01-12',
        '01-16',
        '521');
```

Comment: I think I have now, havent I?

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are trying to insert 13 values into a 14 column set.

```
#  field             value
--------------------------
 1 user_id           2
 2 membership_number 0001
 3 weight            75kgs
 4 height            6ft
 5 progress          lost 5kgs
 6 meal_plan         chicken and rice
 7 my_programme      ???
 8 trainer_id        2
 9 bank              HSBC
10 card_number       1234123412341234
11 sort_code         401725
12 valid             01-12
13 exp               01-16
14 security_number   521
```

Nagaraj S is right. you omitted "my_programme"

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all.

You've listed fourteen columns to add data to, but only gave thirteen values to insert into the table.

The fact that `user_id` is a foreign key is irrelevant; the `insert` statement does not reference the `user` table.

Answer (score 0):

The number of values in the list after `VALUES` is not the same as the number of fields in the query.  You have `14` columns in the `INSERT`, but only supplying `13 VALUES`